# Javascript board game: looking for optimization

Tags: javascript, android, optimization

I'm working on a html/javascript game for android. It's a board game which does the following.
It has tiles of different colors and user can place one tile (chosen programatically) on the board. If we get 4 or more tiles of the same color/shape we score some points and these tiles will disappear. The tiles above the removed tiles will replace them and new tiles will be added to the empty places. The image below shows how it works (this is just an example, the real board can have different dimensions):

[image]

The Tiles are `<img>` elements with their ids stored in an array which I use to check for matches and replacement.

It all works pretty well but once the new tiles are added to board I need to examine the whole board to check if new matches are avalable. And I want some advice here, because examining the whole board can be really slow. Is there a way I can do this efficiently?
Here's what I thought about doing:
[image]

Given the previous example,I thought about examining only the elements in the red area, i.e. only the elements that have been moved or added. It can be effective if the tiles move vertically, as I'll only have to check the moved/added tiles and it'll give me the new matches. But in case where I remove tiles horizontally it can be problematic, because if these tiles are at the bottom i'll have to examine the whole board and i confront the same problem.

Any advice or suggestion will be appreciated.

Note: I didn't add any code because it simply consists of checking the lines and columns for a given tile and look for matches. But if needed I can provide it.

EDIT: Before anyone can object I want to inform that I just added this question to Game Development section as I didn't receive any answers here :).

EDIT: Adding my code

```
function initializeBoard(){
    //items is an array which contains tiles/images names
    for(var i=0; i < totalItems; i++)
        board[i+1] = Math.floor(Math.random() * (items.length - 1)) + 1;
    for(var i=0; i < totalItems; i++)
    {
        if( !(i % numberShapesXAxis) )
            document.write("<BR>");

        document.write("<img src=\"images/"+ items[board[i+1]]+ ".gif\" style = \"border:0; height:"+ itemSize+ "px; width:"+ itemSize+ "px;\"  name=\"t", i+1,"\" onclick = \"replaceAndCheck(", i+1, ")\"><\/a>");
   }
}
//so basically  board contains image ids.
```

Comment: I hope you're storing lines and columns not only as references to the images? I think yes, you have to provide your code (at least those parts that initialise your data structures, and your current move logic).

Comment: @Bergi I've added my board initializing code

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if there is a new match when you move a stone. So when stone x moves down you check if the new position of X creates a match. That way you can create a recursive kind of method.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. the way i see things if I use your method and i remove tiles horizontally, i'll check for matches for one tile then according to changes made by this tile (if it has matches) i'll check another new tile. And once there's no match for a new tile i'll start coming back one level and check the second tile and restart the whole process. If that's what I have to do, wouldn't it be very slow?

Comment: For every stone you add you only have to check horizontal and vertical.  So that is not a lot of processing. Say you move 1 block down. You would only have to check the stone beneath the block to see if it can make a new row. Because the stones above the stones are still the same (if its not the upper row). It would take longer to check the whole field from time to time.

Comment: i totally agree with you but what i was trying to say is i'l check vertically and horizontally for one stone, if there are matches the line or column will be removed, the tiles above them will shift down  and new tiles will take their places. And it's possible that new matches will be available. You do agree that to check if any new matches exist I'll have to check all new tiles ?